# Why does tabular not work correctly inside \ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff?

Tags: tables, expl3

I have discovered that `tabular` doesn't seem to work as expected inside `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` and I suspect it's because of the way white space is treated. Is that correct?

Here is an MWE. It seems that, among other things, `\tabularnewline` is not observed.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zzzz}{ m }
{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\small}p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth}}
      name & & & \tabularnewline
      \ttfamily\footnotesize{\token_to_str:c #1} & & & \tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\small}p{0.25\linewidth} >{\small}p{0.25\linewidth} >{\small}p{0.25\linewidth}}
      base & derived & alternate \tabularnewline
      \footnotesize{BU} & 
      \footnotesize{DU} &
      \footnotesize{AU}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello.

\zzzz{something}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting example! The issue is indeed that spaces are ignored inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`, but not for the reason you think.  I'll add `\fbox`es around your tables to help you see the issue better:

> [image]

See how the second table is right next to the first and it's overflowing the page border?  In fact, if you look at the terminal you'll see:

```
Overfull \hbox (342.37389pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--28
```

which means exactly that: your line is `342 pt` too wide (for comparison, the standard classes set `\linewidth=345pt`, so that's an *entire `\linewidth`* too large!).

The problem is that if you write this in “normal syntax”:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{...}
  ...
\end{tabular}  % <-- here
\begin{tabular}{...}
  ...
\end{tabular}
```

the horizontal list will contain `<table><space><table>`, so a line break is possible between them, whereas in `expl3` syntax the space in the marked line is ignored, so the tables are “glued” together, so they overflow the page.  It's exactly the same as if you typed `z<newline>z` in both cases:  in `expl3` syntax you will see `zz` in the PDF, while in normal syntax you'll see `z z`.

Adding a `~` (or a `\par`) after the first `\end{tabular}` will make it work:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zzzz}{ m }
{%
  \begin{center}
    \dim_set:Nn \fboxrule { 1sp } \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep { 0pt }
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\small}p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth}}
      name & & & \tabularnewline
      \ttfamily\footnotesize{\token_to_str:c {#1}} & & & \tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}}~
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{>{\small}p{0.25\linewidth} >{\small}p{0.25\linewidth} >{\small}p{0.25\linewidth}}
      base & derived & alternate \tabularnewline
      \footnotesize{BU} & 
      \footnotesize{DU} &
      \footnotesize{AU}
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{center}
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello.

\zzzz{something}
\end{document}
```

---

The `expl3` syntax is usually not recommended for writing, because it~is~cumbersome~to~write~tildes~instead~of~spaces and because sometimes the issue is much harder to spot (you just saw one case of that :).  If you just want to use some `expl3` function in normal text (in this case it seems to be `\token_to_str:c`) I'd recommend you do:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \TokenToStrC \token_to_str:c
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and use the more convenient `\TokenToStrC`.

---

Final point, your usage of `\token_to_str:c #1` is not doing what you think it's doing.  `\token_to_str:c {something}` is equivalent to `\token_to_str:N \something` which is equivalent to `\string \something`.  The problem is that you didn't use braces around the argument, so `\token_to_str:c something` is doing `\token_to_str:N \s omething`, which just *happens* to produce the same typeset output as the correct version, but it's doing something very different underneath.

Comment: +1: Sherlock Holmes!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Elementary my dear Kuehner ;-)

Comment: Simply amazing. Thank you. Regarding the table, I'm porting some code from `LaTeX2e` to `expl3` so I gather I should avoid `expl3` code in a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL You're welcome!  Regarding `expl3` in `tabular`: there is nothing _wrong_ in doing that, but it can make debugging cumbersome.  I'd suggest you use `expl3` for data/code, and leave typesetting things in usual 2e syntax, but that's just coding choice, not something enforced in any way: go with what suits you best

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL the issue is unrelated to tabular you see exactly the same if you do `x<newline>x`  that normally you may get a linebreak in the output between the x but inside expl3 area you would get xx with no linebreak possible.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.